# Is there a way to transform messages for SQS queues which are subscribed to SNS topics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have different SQS queues which are subscribed to SNS topics.

However, the different queues need to receive the messages in different formats, not 1:1.

I'd image writing a lambda function for this purpose.
However, from what I've seen, I'd need to implementing this myself, as there doesn't seem to be a built-in mechanism for that.

Is there a way to perhaps invoke a lambda function in the middle of the transmission from SNS to SQS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to perhaps invoke a lambda function in the middle of
>   the transmission from SNS to SQS?

In this case you would simply unsubscribe the SQS queues from the SNS topic, and configure the Lambda function to subscribe to the SNS topic instead. Then you would code the Lambda function to perform the necessary translation, and then send the message to the SQS queues using the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tools-sdks/) for the language you wrote the Lambda function with.

You could have one Lambda function that accepts the message from SNS and sends to every queue, or multiple Lambda functions, one for each queue, each subscribed to the SNS topic.

Comment: Thank you, Mark! Say I have one lambda function which sends out translated messages to multiple queues. Couldn't there be a major delay between sending the message from, say, the first queue to the 100th?

Comment: If you have that many queues, then yes there could be at least a slight delay. That's why I mentioned that you could also setup one Lambda function per queue, or at least split it up into several Lambda functions.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Would the way to implement this be to have a single lambda subscribed to the topic which asynchronously invokes other lambdas to do the forwarding?

Comment: There's no reason to have a single Lambda subscribed to the topic. Multiple Lambdas can all be subscribed to the SNS topic.

Comment: Yes, but the logic in the lambdas would essentially be the same (the only thing that would change is the queue name). So, wouldn't I need to deploy multiple lambdas with a lot of duplication in that case?

Comment: In the interest of performance, you probably want multiple lambdas deployed. In the interest of code-reuse you might want to build most of this as a Lambda layer that is then included in each of the deployed Lambda functions.

Comment: That sounds plausible. If I use single lambda for now to distribute to all queues, what about the filtering? One of the things I found attractive about using SNS was the filter policy I could set on every queue. I guess I would need to implement that logic myself now, as the queues are not directly subscribed to SNS, right?

Comment: You would still implement the SNS filtering, just with the Lambda function's subscription to the SNS topic now. I didn't realize you were doing filtering, I thought you were fanning out every message from SNS to every queue. If that's not the case then you might just need one Lambda function subscribed to the unfiltered topic and perform the filtering/routing/translation in the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201956/discussion-between-ohmad-and-mark-b).